# URL Rewrite Rule to redirect https://oldhostname/oldsubfolder to https://newhostname

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-hosting

I've been racking my brain trying to work out how to make this happen and am starting to think it isn't possible? I've tried numerous variations with the latest being:

```
<rule name="Redirect Website" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^oldsubfolder(.*)$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^oldhostname$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://newhostname/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This is for an internal website. Any thoughts? I do have the "oldhostname" set as an alias to point to the "newhostname" in our DNS but I am getting 404s so it's getting there but not hitting the right page. I'd also need to trailing links to carry over as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below rule and make sure that the folder path does exist in the new domain.

```
<rule name="Redirect Specific Folder" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^oldsubfolder/(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^oldhostname$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://newhostname/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

as you can see it will use the test as the {R:1}. so based on that your new url will be https://newhostname/test

[image]

Comment: So this makes logical sense but for some reason I am still getting a 404. Aside from the DNS alias is there anything else needed beyond the URL rewrite? Do I need to add "oldhostname" to my bindings to make this work?

Comment: @GregDavis open a privacy browser tab please. Redirection will be cached otherwise.

Comment: @GregDavis could you try accessing both the url without using the url rewrite rule to check is it accessible or not

Comment: Wanted to update that I will unfortunately not have a resolution for this. Was laid off while working on this (not because of this ;)  ) and didn't have a chance to resolve it. In fact we were going to simply move everyone over to a new url with an announcement instead.